# Advantages of PAE

Tags: operating-system, processor

I've read an interesting article at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366796(v=vs.85).aspx. It states that:

- Physical Address Extension (PAE) is a processor feature that enables x86 processors to access more than 4 GB of physical memory on capable versions of Windows.
- PAE does not change the amount of virtual address space available to a process. Each process running in 32-bit Windows is still limited to a 4 GB virtual address space.

Would you please tell me what advantages of this feature are? Is it only useful for reducing amount of time OSs handle paging?

Comment: I think the article is very self-explanatory. Your 32-bit pointers/addresses can address up to 2**32 bytes. But you want more. PAE lets you do that. Read the CPU manual for how PAE works.

Comment: What is your practical programming question?

Comment: @RaymondChen: I don't have any programming question here. Just curious about how OSs may be better if PAE is enabled. :)

Comment: The FAQ says that SO is for practical programming questions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PAE is useful when you have more than one application running, and consuming memory. Like if you have 16GB of RAM on a 32bit machine, without PAE, you'd be able to use only 4GB for all applications, and the OS itself. But with PAE, you could have each process its own 32 bit address space, so you could use all the 16GB of RAM, just not from one process...

Put the DB and the application server instances on the same box for example, and it becomes useful.

**EDIT**
In the first approach, this was not clear: one does not need to have a 64bit CPU to be able to use PAE! From Pentium Pro up, the CPU should be able to use it:

> In computing, Physical Address Extension (PAE) is a feature to allow 32-bit x86 processors to access a physical address space (including random access memory and memory mapped devices) larger than 4 gigabytes.

(From: [Wikipedia: Physical Address Extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension))

Also recommended to read:

[Wikipedia: 3GB barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier)

[Serverfault: Which CPUs do/do not support PAE](https://serverfault.com/questions/85980/what-processors-do-do-not-support-pae)

Comment: So PAE-anabled 32bit OSes don't have to swap in/swap out as frequently as other 32bit OSes?

Comment: @anhldbk: Under 4GB RAM, they will behave the same. More than 4GB of RAM can be used in a PAE box. Individual processes still only have 32bits of address space. This means that with 5 applications using 1GB each plus the OS, on the same machine with 8 GB RAM and PAE, you can have all of them in RAM, and still have some headroom to grow. Without PAE, no matter how much RAM the box has above 4GB, it will only be able to use only 4GB for all processes, (which is around 3-3.5 GB at best due to the 3GB barrier mentioned above), which results in unused memory and most likely a lot of swapping.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation. :)

Answer (score -2):

To leverage PAE you do need a 64-bit processor. and bus size is 36 bits.

It's like your hardware is capable of accessing more than 4GB Memory, but intentionally/unintentionally you have installed a 32-bit operating system, which by default does not allow you to access beyond 0xffffffff, so put additional kernel module which will let you access everything.

Comment: Possibility to extend physical address space was first implemented in Pentium Pro processors. Since Pentium III PSE-36 is present. Current versions of PAE allow up to 52 bit physical address space and are required in IA-32e (64 bit) mode.

Comment: may be PAE can, but even my processor (Intel Core I5) has 36 bit physical and 48 bits virtual. So I wrote 36 bits there.

Comment: To know limitations of PAE Intel Manual 3A section 4.4 and 4.5 may be better source than possibilities of i5 processors, especially when PAE itself is not the only thing that may limit available address space. There are Intel Xenon E7 processors that can use 42 bit physical address space.